# [mysql]: does using AFTER column keyword affect migration speed

Tags: sql, mysql

I was trying schema migration on a huge table. When tried it using `AFTER` keyword, migration was very slow compared to the normal case without `AFTER`.

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN newcol BOOLEAN AFTER oldcol;
```

Is there any explanation to this, or it was just some coincidence(traffic on mysql server when tried with AFTER).

Couldn't find anything related to this in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190228/performance-of-mysql-alter-table-add-column-after-column-on-a-large-table#comment10115815_8190228

Comment: In the default storage engine InnoDB, it should not make any difference. Adding a column requires a table-copy regardless of where you add the column in the row, and doing the table-copy is likely to account for the great majority of time, unless the table has a trivial number of rows. If it seemed to take longer, then it must be a coincidence of high traffic, or else a trick of perception.

Comment: @BillKarwin noted. Using InnoDb engine. Seems like it's due to high traffic only. Thank you.